# Can I run E2E loading tests with locust?

Tags: jmeter, locust, e2e

I am trying to do some E2E loading tests with my website

For HTTP requests, I have used jMeter for loading tests.
For E2E chatGPT suggests that Locust could do both E2E and HTTP request loading test.

But I could find any E2E loading tests instruction in Locust [documentation](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/)

I just want to ask whether Locust support E2E loading tests?

Comment: What do you mean by E2E in this context?

Comment: @Cyberwiz UI loading tests. Sorry for any confusion. I'll try jMeter with WebDriver Sampler

Answer (score 0):

If by "E2E" tests you mean running real browsers - take a look at [Locust Plugins](https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins), there is one which [provides Locust integration with Selenium](https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/webdriver_ex.py)

JMeter can also integrated with Selenium browser automation framework via [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin, the plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try jMeter with WebDrive Sampler. I want to like your answer but I am not enough reputation yet :V